# Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped. (makes no sense!)

Tags: debugging, parsing, facebook-opengraph

A website I have will absolutely not work on Facebook's Debugger.  I constantly get Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped (that's it).  It's a WordPress 3.5 installation running Yoast's SEO plugin with OG data enabled.

I run many WordPress 3.5 sites from the same host (Dreamhost), with the SAME plugin that works perfectly on Debugger.  If you checked the source code on the page not working, you can see the correct og: data.

All no-indexes have been unchecked, maintenance mode is off.  I can't imagine a wordpress theme causing it to fail (I switched the theme to double check).

http://www.pompeya.com

I even tried the fbrefresh using http://www.pompeya.com?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING

When I go to facebook, it IS pulling the text og data, but not the 200x200px PNG pic that I've included.  Again, I'm operating the same tactics as all my other wordpress sites, which are working.

Need help why Debugger can't even see the site!

Comment: Duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site