# Error Parsing URL Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

this would be yet another question for the vague Facebook Error Message: 
"Error Parsing URL  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped", 
as other posts regarding this issue went unanswered:

[#1. by Vincent Guyard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256490/facebook-url-linter-gives-error-parsing-input-url-no-data-was-scraped)

[#2. by Daniel Tiru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943897/error-parsing-input-url-no-data-was-scraped)

[#3. by Fernando Quirino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617821/facebook-debugger-error-parsing-url-error-parsing-input-url-no-data-was-scra)

[#4. by user1964054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242417/error-parsing-input-url-no-data-was-scraped-makes-no-sense)

and this list goes on..

our case is a bit different, we have recently purchased a new domain name and performed 
a transition from our old domain to the new one.

before the transition we were able to promote and advertise our website on Facebook.

after the transition we cannot do so neither with our new domain name nor with our old domain, attempting to do so we get a general error message:
"You've selected an object that cannot be promoted. Please choose a different object".

as if we have been black-listed for reasons which are beyond our knowledge.

The transition by it self was straight forward by adding a new binding to our website
on our IIS server for incoming requests with our new domain name, that is, we have not 
changed our contents, nor did we change in our website pages code or structure, or for this matter changed our IP or migrated to another server.

when we tried to debug our url with: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
we got Facebook infamous vague error message: "Error Parsing URL Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.".

considering that we have not made any changes to our website in terms of content, structure or code, we presume that perhaps our new domain name "has a history" with Facebook.

Turning to Facebook support we were directed here..
with much respect for stackoverflow (and there is very much!), it is a big shame that Facebook detaches its self from supporting users of its own platform.

Back to our problem, has anyone encountered the scenario listed above? 
or has a vague idea :) what might be the problem? and perhaps how can it be solved?
or where we can approach with it for consulting?

As for now we did not yet receive a feedback from Facebook to our issue.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide any updates? I got the same error message and all the questions stay unanswered…